# Table is not showing properly in IE 9

Tags: html, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am having a problem with a table. The table seems pretty ok with FF and Chome but IE shows some space top and below of the table. Could not figure out how to solve this. Any ideas to solve this problem? Thank you

[image: IE vs FF/Chrome difference]

Comment: You should provide some minimal HTML/CSS code besides just a screenshot.

Comment: can you put your code on http://jsfiddle.net and share?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wcq6V/1/ here you can the code. its a bit messy I think :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a reset.css and can you post us some of your code?

Comment: This is the code. http://jsfiddle.net/wcq6V/1/ I have seperated it from other parts, saved as a new doc but the issue with IE still continiues:(

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wcq6V/5/ Fixed it, I added a style reset (as I mentioned) and removed min-height: 255px;

Comment: Thank you! :) it worked. but removing min-height affected other parts of the site now:(

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be a you would need to set a height definition on the second box. If that doesn't work, I'd look at the padding definitions.

Answer (score 0):

you will two points.

1. give `vertical-align:top;` to side box
2. if you give any padding? IE will takes padding double